# regular expressions - match all anchors with optional attributes

Tags: php, regex

I have a wysiwyg editor in my back end, and it is tripping up the first regular expression I wrote. This is in PHP4, using `preg_replace()`. I'm capturing the URI and linked text.

```
@<a\shref=\"http[s]?://([^\"]*)\"[]>(.*)<\/a>@siU
```

The client wanted all external links to open in a new window, so that's the expression I was using to find all (hopefully) external links, but leave internal, page anchor links, etc

I realised the wysiwyg editor also adds `style="font-weight: bold"` if the user selects bold on the link. I've only recently started learning regular expressions so I'm unsure how to go about this problem.

How would I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this should match it alright:

```
/<a\s+([^>]*)href="https?:\/\/([^"]*)"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>/
```

The useful thing here is the lazy match. `*?` it means that it'll match only as much as it absolutely needs to, as opposed to the regular match, which is greedy.

To demonstrate, with this text:

> `a b c d a b c d`

these regexes will have different results:

```
/a.*c/    selects: "a b c d a b c"
/a.*?c/   selects: "a b c"
```