# How to check if a string is an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript

Whats the best way to check if a string is an anchor tag in JS?

Some examples:

```
<a href='./page'>Link</a> //returns true

<a href='./page'> //returns false
```

Is there a quick and easy way?
In the most simplest form. As long as there is an opening `<a>` and a closing `</a>`

Comment: Would `<a></a>` count as an anchor tag?

Comment: How are you getting the strings?

Comment: @blex Yes thats an anchor tag. 
@DaveNewton say like I did `var string = "<a></a>"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regex for this:

```
function isAnchor(str){
    return /^\<a.*\>.*\<\/a\>/i.test(str);
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var testStrings = [
    '<a href="./page">Hello</a>',           // true
    '<a>Hi</a>',                            // true
    '<a href=\'test.php\'>Yo</a>',          // true
    '<A HREF=\'test.php\'>UPPERCASE</A>',   // true  - not case-sensitive
    'test',                                 // false
    '<a href="./page">Hello',               // false - tag not closed
    '<span>Hi again</span>'                 // false
];

for(var i=0; i<testStrings.length; i++){
    var str = testStrings[i];
    document.body.innerHTML += str + ' => ' + isAnchor(str) + '<br>';
}

function isAnchor(str){
    return /^\<a.*\>.*\<\/a\>/i.test(str);
}
```

Comment: '<aaaa>Hi again</a>' will validate also, which is not correct. I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158346/regular-expression-for-anchor-tag-whith-all-attibutes) with a more complete regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will point you in the right direction:

```
var stringOne = "<a href='./page'>Link</a>";
var stringTwo = "<a href='./page'>";

function isA(str){
    if (str.indexOf("href") > -1 && str.indexOf("</a>") > -1){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

console.log(isA(stringOne));
console.log(isA(stringTwo));
```