# JS - find all instances of a string and wrap in anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to wrap all instances of a string with an anchor tag.

Basically on our site I want to find any instance of `myBrand` or `myBrand.com` and wrap them in an anchor like `<a href="/">myBrand</a>` or `<a href="/">myBrand.com</a>`.

However, I want to be able to find all instances of this no matter how far buried they are in various elements on my page and see if they already are linked, and this is where I am having an issue.

### Edit

I've edited the snippet to what I have now but am still having difficulties:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('body').forEach(function(el){
  var text = el.innerHTML.match(/myBrand/g);
  
  console.log(text.parentElement); // how do i get the parent?
  
  if(isAnchor(text.parentElement)){
    //
  }else{
      var newtext = el.innerHTML.replace(/myBrand/g, '<a href="/">myBrand</a>');
    el.innerHTML = newtext;
  }
});

function isAnchor(str){
    return /^\<a.*\>.*\<\/a\>/i.test(str);
}
```

```html
<body>

myBrand

<h1>myBrand.com</h1>

<p>This is a div that mentions myBrand</p>

<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
    <td>This is myBrand's table header</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>myBrand.com</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<a href="/">myBrand.com</a>

</body>
```

Comment: What do you want for if it's already inside an anchor? Do you want to wrap in another anchor?

Comment: So basically all instances of myBrand should link to the home page, if it is already wrapped in an anchor then i'd just leave it the way it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with using `innerHTML` to replace the content of html is any data or events assigned to existing elements will be removed as soon as you set new html using innerHTML. And doing this at the level of `document.body` is a very bad idea.

So, I wrote a solution that uses text nodes instead. Text nodes cannot have events, so removing a text node and adding a new does not have any side affects (except for selection, which we can ignore for this case).

```js
function iterateTextNodes(container, callback) {
    Array.from(container.childNodes).forEach(node => {
        if (node.nodeType === node.TEXT_NODE) {
            callback(node);
        } else if (node.tagName !== 'A') {
            /* Do not go inside anchor tags checking for text nodes,
               this get rids of the problem with nodes that are already
               inside anchor tags */
            iterateTextNodes(node, callback);
        }
    });
}

function getAnchor(href, content) {
    const anchor = document.createElement('A');
    anchor.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content));
    anchor.setAttribute('href', href);
    return anchor;
}

iterateTextNodes(document.body, function (node) {
    const parentNode = node.parentNode;
    // Check for myBrand.com first and then check for myBrand, to handle all the cases
    node.nodeValue.split('myBrand.com').forEach((string, i) => {
        i && parentNode.insertBefore(getAnchor('/', 'myBrand.com'), node);
        string.split('myBrand').forEach((string, i) => {
            i && parentNode.insertBefore(getAnchor('/', 'myBrand'), node);
            parentNode.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(string), node);
        });
    });
    parentNode.removeChild(node);
});
```

```html
<body>

myBrand

<h1>myBrand.com</h1>

<p>This is a div that mentions myBrand</p>

<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
    <td>This is myBrand's table header</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>myBrand.com</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<a href="/">myBrand.com</a>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` with RegEx to set the `innerHTML` property like the following way:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/myBrand(?!\.)/g, '<a href="/">myBrand</a>');
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/myBrand.com/g, '<a href="/">myBrand.com</a>');
```

```html
<body>

  myBrand

  <h1>myBrand.com</h1>

  <p>This is a div that mentions myBrand</p>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>This is myBrand's table header</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>myBrand.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <a href="/">myBrand.com</a>

</body>
```

Comment: This will only select elements which match `tr td`. I think OP needs to match all text nodes

Comment: Ok so this is getting me there, I changed it to: `document.querySelectorAll('body').forEach(function(el){
  var text = el.innerHTML.replace(/myBrand/g, '<a href="/">myBrand</a>');
  el.innerHTML = text;
});` any idea how I could differentiate myBrand and myBrand.com or if something is already wrapped in an anchor?

Comment: @PaddyHallihan, please check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148051/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-an-anchor-tag

Comment: Thanks this is great, I'm still having a few difficulties though, i've updated my snippet.

Comment: @PaddyHallihan, `match` returns an array of string, which is not a *node* element, that's why there is no `parentElement` exist on that.....

Comment: @PaddyHallihan, I was late to notice the text without tag. The solution seems pretty simply with regex and `innerHTML`. Updated the answer, please check:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) for this:

```
function textContaining(phrase) {
  return document.evaluate(
    "//text()[contains(., '" + phrase + "')]",
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null
  )
}
```

You can then iterate through the results like so:

```
var result = textContaining(phrase)
for (var i = 0; i < result.snapshotLength; ++i) {
  var originalNode = result.snapshotItem(i)
  // ...
}
```

Once you've got a list of matching `#text` nodes, you simply need to filter out any whose [.parentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement) is an `<a>` tag.

Alternatively, you could use the jQuery [`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) function to check parents-of-parents, so as to account for cases like `<a><span>sometext</span></a>`, rather than just direct-child scenarios.