# Replace multiple html-tags in react-native to Text

Tags: react-native

I have a JSON file with multiple string, each string often contains an a-tag for example. I manage to replace the last A tag but I need to be able to change both in a string.

My map function looks like this:

```
            <Text style={styles.text}>
           
               {this.state.selectedData.map((item) =>(
                   <Text style={{width:ScreenWidth}}>{this.rerenderHTML(item)}</Text>
     
                ))}
            </Text>
```

My function looks like this:

```
rerenderHTML(item){

    if (item.indexOf('<i>') > -1)
    {
        var newItem =  item.substring(
            item.lastIndexOf("<i>") + 3, 
            item.lastIndexOf("</i>")
        );

        console.log("italic:"+newItem)

        var itemItalic = <Text style={{fontStyle:'italic'}}>{newItem}{"\n"}{"\n"}</Text>

            return itemItalic
     
    }else if(item.indexOf('<a') > -1){



            var  newItem =  item.substring(
                item.lastIndexOf('href="') + 6, 
                item.lastIndexOf('"')-16
            );
            
            var firstTillSplit= item.split("<a");
            var afterSplit= item.split("</a>");


            var itemItalic = <Text> {firstTillSplit[0]} <Text style={{color:'red'}} onPress={()=>{Linking.openURL('http://plaatsengids.nl'+newItem)}}>{newItem.replace("/",'')}</Text> {afterSplit[1]} </Text>
        
            var replaceLink = item.replace(/<a[^>]*>|<\/a>/g, "link"); // a try for deleting the a-tag but does only remove the HTML not the text and can't replace with component

            return  itemItalic
    }else{
        return <Text>{item}</Text>;
    }

}
```

The Json file looks like this:

```
"text": [
                     "Buurtschap 't Heeske valt, ook voor de postadressen, onder het dorp <a href=\"/maasbree\" target=\"_blank\">Maasbree</a> <a href=\"/test2\" target=\"_blank\">test 2</a>.",
                     "Maalbeek is een buurtschap in de provincie Limburg, in de streek Noord-Limburg, gemeente Venlo. T/m 2000 gemeente Belfeld.",
                     "De buurtschap Maalbeek valt, ook voor de postadressen, onder het dorp Belfeld.",
                     "De buurtschap heeft geen plaatsnaamborden en wordt ook niet in atlassen of plaatsenlijsten vermeld, maar is nog wel degelijk een buurtschap (zo is ons door inwoners uit de regio gemeld) en dus plaats(naam).",
                  ]
```

The result is that the last a-tag is placed in the first place, so "test2" and the last A-tag remains visible. In this example, first "Maasbree" must come and then "test2"

I know that it is possible to open a webview with A-tags, but that is not possible within my project.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need some regex to get the job done. Here's an example of some of the ways that you can search/replace/manipulate that text:

```
const str = "Buurtschap 't Heeske valt, ook voor de postadressen, onder het dorp <a href=\"/maasbree\" target=\"_blank\">Maasbree</a> <a href=\"/test2\" target=\"_blank\">test 2</a>.";

const regex = RegExp(/<a\s+([^>]*)href="([^"]*)".*?>(.*?)<\/a>/gm);
console.log(Array.from(str.matchAll(regex)))
console.log(str.replace(/<a\s+([^>]*)href="([^"]*)".*?>(.*?)<\/a>/gm, "$1 Link $2"));
console.log(str.replace(/<a\s+([^>]*)href="([^"]*)".*?>(.*?)<\/a>/gm, "LINK"));
```

Which yields:

```
[['<a href=\'/maasbree\' target=\'_blank\'>Maasbree</a>','','/maasbree','Maasbree'],['<a href=\'/test2\' target=\'_blank\'>test 2</a>','','/test2','test 2']]
"Buurtschap 't Heeske valt, ook voor de postadressen, onder het dorp  Link /maasbree  Link /test2."
"Buurtschap 't Heeske valt, ook voor de postadressen, onder het dorp LINK LINK."
```

The regular expression I used is a modification from these answers: [Regular expression for anchor tag with all attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158346/regular-expression-for-anchor-tag-with-all-attributes)

Then, I do a few things with it:

1. In the event that you need to capture the links or text, I show you the result of using `matchAll`
2. I show you replacement with the different capture groups ($1 and $2)
3. I show replacing the whole thing with just the word `LINK`.

Hopefully these can get you started manipulating the text in the way that you need it.

Update to get the specific terms you were looking for in the matches:

```
const matches = Array.from(str.matchAll(regex))
const firstLinkHref = matches[0][2]; // == /maasbree
const firstLinkText = matches[0][3]; // == Maasbree
```

Comment: thanks for your clear explanation! I almost have what I need. An array item is for example: ['<a href=\'/maasbree\' target=\'_blank\'> Maasbree </a>', '', '/ maasbree', 'Maasbree']

Do you have any idea how I can name the third and fourth object in the array, so only "/ maasbree" and "maasbree" separately. I run the Array items as follows:

When I log on console items [i] [3] I get an error, and I can't use split function either.

Comment: Are you using Array.from like I did in my example?

Comment: no I use this one. Also an array is created but 1 array item is: "['<a href=\'/maasbree\' target=\'_blank\'> Maasbree </a>', '', '/ maasbree', 'Maasbree '] "and the other" [' <a href=\'/test2\' target=\'_blank\'> test 2 </a> ',' ',' / test2 ',' test 2 '] "as I can still take that last step then it is solved! so I only need "/ maasbree" and "maasbree" from the first item and "/ test2" and "test 2" from the second one

Comment: I will be back in front of a computer in the morning and can try to answer then. For now, I would suggest experimenting in the debugger. Looks to me like you have all the info to figure it out! Untested for now, it looks like it would be Array.from(str.match...)[0][2] and ... [0][3]. But, not in front of a computer to check.

Comment: I've edited my answer to get exactly the parameters out you were looking for.